# TYPO3-6.2 Extbase custom content type -> invalid value

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I made an extbase Extension for custom content elements. Since this is my first extension I started with a simple "hello_world_ce". This are my files:

**ext_tables.php**

```
<?php
$TCA['tt_content']['types']['hello_world_ce']['showitem'] = '--palette--;LLL:EXT:hello_world/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_mod.xlf:content_element.hello_world.general;general, --palette--;LLL:EXT:hello_world/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_mod.xlf:content_element.hello_world.header;header';
```

**ext_localconf.php**

```
<?php
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPageTSConfig('<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:'.$_EXTKEY.'/Configuration/TypoScript/ModWizards.ts">');
```

**ModWizards.ts**

```
mod.wizards {
    newContentElement {
        wizardItems {
            hello_world {
                header = LLL:EXT:hello_world/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_mod.xlf:content_tab_header
                elements {
                    hello_world_ce {
                        icon = gfx/c_wiz/regular_header.gif
                        title = LLL:EXT:hello_world/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_mod.xlf:content_element.hello_world
                        description = LLL:EXT:hello_world/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_mod.xlf:content_element.hello_world.description
                        tt_content_defValues {
                            CType = hello_world_ce
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            show = *
        }
    }
}
```

In the TYPO3 Backend I see my content element and can add it to a page but the dropdown menu for the content type says **INVALID VALUE ("hello_world_ce")**

What am I missing?

EDIT: I found the missing part. I needed to add my content type to the CType array

**ext_tables.php**

```
$backupCTypeItems = $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['CType']['config']['items'];
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['CType']['config']['items'] = array(
    array(
        'LLL:EXT:'.$_EXTKEY.'/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_mod.xlf:content_tab_header',
        '--div--'
    ),
    array(
        'LLL:EXT:'.$_EXTKEY.'/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_mod.xlf:content_element.hello_world',
        'hello_world_ce',
        'i/tt_content_header.gif'
    )
);
foreach($backupCTypeItems as $key => $value){
    $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['CType']['config']['items'][] = $value;
}
```

Comment: It is not a good solution to change the TCA directly, use core functions. (You can just remove the solution from the question and accept one of the answers or add your own answer).

Comment: Also, changing TCA in ext_tables.php is outdated, should be in Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php

Answer (score -1):

The question was edited, but I think there is a better way to achieve the solution.

Only to be clear about the problem:

The content element **hello_world_ce** was not added to the "types" dropdown by adding a new content element.

The hint in the question is correct it was not defined for the CType field. 
But instead of manipulating the array you could use a core function:

```
 // Adds the content element to the "Type" dropdown
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPlugin(
   array(
      'LLL:EXT:your_extension_key/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_mod.xlf:content_element.hello_world',
      'hello_world_ce',
      'i/tt_content_header.gif'
   ),
   'CType',
   'your_extension_key'
);
```

Here is a very good example of how to add your own content element in the version [TYPO3 7.6](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/fluid_styled_content/7.6/AddingYourOwnContentElements/Index.html).

Note: This function is accessible in TYPO3 6.2 as well.